# Getting stuck in Dictionary Project in C

Tags: c

I prefer to create a `Dictionary` object and add 3 words to it.
My program has no compilation error but gets a run time error in the second for loop, is the problem in `addNewWord` function? Do I need pass a pointer to the `DictionaryWord` object ?

Please help me.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct{
    char* name;
    char* mean;
} Words;

typedef struct{
    Words* word;
    int size;
} Dictionary;

Dictionary createNewDictionary();
Words createNewWord();
void addNewWord(Words newword, Dictionary dic);

Dictionary createNewDictionary(){
    Dictionary dic;
    dic.size = 0;
    dic.word = (Words*)malloc(dic.size*sizeof(Words));
    return dic;
}

Words createNewWord(){
    Words newword;
    newword.name = (char*)malloc(30*sizeof(char));
    newword.mean = (char*)malloc(30*sizeof(char));
    printf("============================\n");
    printf("Enter word: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]", newword.name);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("\nEnter meaning: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]", newword.mean); 
    return newword;
}

void addNewWord(Words newword, Dictionary dic){
    dic.size++;
    dic.word = (Words*)realloc(dic.word,dic.size*sizeof(Words));
    strcpy(dic.word[dic.size-1].name, newword.name);
    strcpy(dic.word[dic.size-1].mean, newword.mean);
}

int main(){
    Dictionary d = createNewDictionary();
    for (int i=0;i<3;i++){
        addNewWord(createNewWord(), d);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the run time error? Where is the "second" for loop? I can only see one.

Comment: All function parameters are passed by value in C. That means you are passing a *copy* of `d` to `addNewWord`. Thus all the modifications to `dic` in that function do not affect the caller's original `d` variable. The result is that the same `d.word` is being freed multiple times (hence the error on the second loop).

Comment: 1) Don't cast the result of `malloc` & friends or `void *` in general. 2) `fflush(stdin)` invokes _undefined behaviour_. 3) See [ask].

Comment: @kaylum: I used passing by pointer but it has the same problem...

Comment: @Olaf: i was wondering if u explain more...

Comment: @Applepine: I don't see how to be more clear. Remove the casts and about 2) serach for it! Your program can do anything, including nasal deamons appearing.

Comment: @Applepine Well then you have something else wrong with your code. Lets fix one problem at a time. What you have shown is certainly wrong for the reason that I have mentioned. So there's no point continuing with it. If you have tried the pointer approach and still get a problem then please show that code - we can't identify what might be wrong with code we can't see.

Comment: @kaylum : see the changes suggested by me, the code works perfectly then.

Comment: @Jarvis I doubt it works perfectly. At a minimum the first `malloc` needs to be a `realloc`.

Comment: @kaylum : Yeah, thanks for pointing that out, the answer is edited. Check the code at `pastebin` to see for yourself.

Comment: @Olaf: ah sr, because im writing in cpp file so i casted in malloc.

Comment: @kaylum: this is the code i fixed before post this ask.
    `void addNewWord(Words newword, Dictionary* dic){
            dic->size++;
     dic->word = (Words*)realloc(dic->word,dic->size*sizeof(Words));
     strcpy(dic->word[dic->size-1].name, newword.name);
     strcpy(dic->word[dic->size-1].mean, newword.mean);
    }`
Via the answer of Jarvis, i forgot allocating for name and mean of dic

Comment: C++ is not C! They are different languages. Use the correct tags! And use the C++ features; writing C-style in C++ is a bad idea. E.g. use `static_cast`, not C-style casts.

Comment: @Olaf: I just have known it since some mins before, because i am using dev c to compile my program. After this post i will change all my code to C, thanks a lot for your advices

Comment: I'm not playing tag wars but since the code presented is pure **C**, the accepted answer is pure **C** and OP states "i will change all my code to C", I'm rolling back the [C++] tag back to [C] and dropping the [dictionary] tag as this post is about *Webster* not "efficient retrieval" as the data is not hashed but stored sequentially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of problem with your code:

Given the longest word in English is around 30 characters, this size allocation is realistic for the word, but not for the defintion:

```
newword.name = (char*)malloc(30*sizeof(char));
newword.mean = (char*)malloc(30*sizeof(char));
```

This makes little obvious sense:

```
dic.size = 0;
dic.word = (Words*)malloc(dic.size*sizeof(Words));
```

you called `malloc()` on zero!  You're only spared by your later `realloc()`.  Even if intentional, it really deserves a comment.

This doesn't really work as `fflush()` is for output streams:

```
fflush(stdin);
```

see: [How to clear input buffer in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7898215/how-to-clear-input-buffer-in-c)  And whatever fix you use has to apply to *both* `scanf()` calls, not just one!

Per @Jarvis, this doesn't work:

```
dic.word = (Words*)realloc(dic.word,dic.size*sizeof(Words));
strcpy(dic.word[dic.size-1].name, newword.name);
strcpy(dic.word[dic.size-1].mean, newword.mean);
```

as you didn't allocate any space for `name` and `mean` in `dic` so you're copying into random memory.

Per @Jarvis, doesn't work:

```
void addNewWord(Words newword, Dictionary dic){
    dic.size++;
    dic.word = (Words*)realloc(dic.word,dic.size*sizeof(Words));
```

You're passing `dic` by value so inside `addnewWord()` you've a copy of `dic` so the original `dic`'s `size` will be the same as it was before the call!

Memory leak:

```
addNewWord(createNewWord(), d);
```

you dropped your handle onto what `createNewWord()` returned so you can never free the memory it `malloc()`'d

You `malloc()` memory but provide no means to eventually free it.

Passing and returning structs by value is a disaster in a situation like this, as the data keeps getting copied.  At the least it's inefficient, at worst its buggy like the `size` issue above.  Rather than risk it, pretend they can only be passed and returned by pointer and you'll be playing it safe and get a better result.

Below is a rework of your code (in **C**) with fixes, style tweaks and an attempt at a consistent terminology.  It also provides some minimal test code and the ability to free your data:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_WORD_LENGTH 30
#define MAX_DEFINITION_LENGTH 1024

typedef struct entry {
    char *word;
    char *definition;
} Entry;

typedef struct dictionary {
    Entry *entries;
    int num_entries, max_entries;
} Dictionary;

Dictionary *createNewDictionary() {
    Dictionary *dictionary = malloc(sizeof(*dictionary));

    dictionary->num_entries = 0;
    dictionary->max_entries = 1;
    dictionary->entries = calloc(dictionary->max_entries, sizeof(*dictionary->entries));

    return dictionary;
}

void freeEntry(Entry *entry) {
    free(entry->word);
    free(entry->definition);
    free(entry);
}

void freeDictionary(Dictionary *dictionary) {
    for (--dictionary->num_entries; dictionary->num_entries >= 0; --dictionary->num_entries) {
        // we can't call freeWord() here -- why.
        free(dictionary->entries[dictionary->num_entries].word);
        free(dictionary->entries[dictionary->num_entries].definition);
    }

    free(dictionary->entries);
    free(dictionary);
}

void purgeInput() {
    int c;

    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) { }
}

Entry *requestNewEntry() {
    Entry *entry = malloc(sizeof(*entry));
    entry->word = malloc(MAX_WORD_LENGTH);
    entry->definition = malloc(MAX_DEFINITION_LENGTH);

    printf("============================\n");
    printf("Enter word: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]", entry->word);

    purgeInput();

    printf("\nEnter definition: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]", entry->definition);

    purgeInput();

    return entry;
}

void addNewEntry(Entry *entry, Dictionary *dictionary) {
    if (dictionary->num_entries == dictionary->max_entries) {
        dictionary->max_entries *= 2;
        dictionary->entries = realloc(dictionary->entries, dictionary->max_entries * sizeof(*dictionary->entries));
        // check if realloc returns NULL and if so, handle the error.
    }

    dictionary->entries[dictionary->num_entries].word = strdup(entry->word);
    dictionary->entries[dictionary->num_entries].definition = strdup(entry->definition);

    dictionary->num_entries++;
}

int main() {
    Dictionary *d = createNewDictionary();

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        Entry *e = requestNewEntry();

        addNewEntry(e, d);

        freeEntry(e);
    }

    printf("\nRead: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < d->num_entries; i++) {
        printf("%s (%lu chars) ", d->entries[i].word, strlen(d->entries[i].definition));
    }
    printf("\n");

    freeDictionary(d);

    return 0;
}
```

**CREATING A PUN DICTIONARY**

```
> ./a.out
============================
Enter word: silkworm

Enter definition: Two silkworms had a race but ended up in a tie.
============================
Enter word: horse

Enter definition: A horse is a stable animal.
============================
Enter word: termite

Enter definition: A termite walks into a pub and asks, "Is the bar tender here?"

Read: silkworm (47 chars) horse (27 chars) termite (62 chars) 
>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for help, i learned a lot of experience from your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I see what's wrong with your code. First of all, you need to pass your `Dictionary` object by `pointer` to the function, `addNewWord`, and in the function `addNewWord`, you again need to allocate memory to each of the `char*` fields, `name` and `mean`, of the `dic` object. Here is the corrected code :

```
void addNewWord(Words newword, Dictionary *dic){
    dic->size++;
    dic->word = (Words*)realloc(dic->word, dic->size*sizeof(Words));
    dic->word[dic->size-1].name = (char*)malloc(30*sizeof(char));  //added
    dic->word[dic->size-1].mean = (char*)malloc(30*sizeof(char));  //added
    strcpy(dic->word[dic->size-1].name, newword.name);
    strcpy(dic->word[dic->size-1].mean, newword.mean);
}
```

Pass the dictionary's address as :

```
addNewWord(createNewWord(), &d);
```

and change the definition as well as prototype of the function as well :

```
void addNewWord(Words newword, Dictionary *dic)
```

Find the complete code here : http://pastebin.com/ZN69hevj

Comment: Isn't `addNewWord(createNewWord(), &d)` a memory leak?